# Unable to install jaspersoft studio in eclipse

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

while trying to install jasper studio in eclipse from eclipse marketplace, I got an the following error.
HTTP Server 'Service Unavailable': http://jasperstudio.sourceforge.net/updates/content.xml
HttpComponents connection error response code 503.

Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)